# Why TSC needed when there is PIT available

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, interrupt

I was reading ["Understanding Linux Kernel"](http://www.kerneltravel.net/downloads/UnderstandLinuxKernel2nd.pdf), where it says about three clocks

1. Real Time Clock
2. Time Stamp Counter (TSC)
3. Programmable Interval timer (PIT)

I have few questions regarding these.

1. Why Real Time clock is not used after computer is powered on?
2. Is it running while the system is running?
3. TSC register uses PIT, then why we need TSC register based timing?
4. The value of IRQ8 from the /proc/interrupts gives 1 for cpu0 and 0
   for others even after system is running for some amount of time. Why
   only one interrupt from IRQ8, which is the real time clock.

This is NOT a homework question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The RTC is not used often because its registers are very slow to access.
2. The RTC is *always* running (that's why it has its own battery). However, nowadays its only purpose is to keep the time while the system is not running.
3. The TSC can be accessed much faster than the PIT.
4. The kernel always tries to use the timer that can be programmed in the most efficient way, so it switches from the PIT to the CPU-local TSC-based timer ([local APIC timer](http://wiki.osdev.org/APIC_timer)) as soon as it detects the latter.
   In `/proc/interrupts`, the LAPIC interrupt does not have a number but is named `LOC`.

Comment: I'll give you +1 if you provide a description of LAPIC since that was not in the Op's original question.